# Solving a system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

(Image Attached)

[image]

I've begun with the hint and found out that $(det\ A)*x=adj\ A*c$ and therefore what x is. My question would be how would I go about finding what $det\ A_i$  is? Should I go about it using the formal definition (summation of permutations)?

Answer (score 1):

In case you'd want to know, this relation is known as Cramer's rule. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer's_rule#Applications) and [Cliffsnotes](http://www.cliffsnotes.com/math/algebra/algebra-ii/linear-equations-in-three-variables/linear-equations-solutions-using-determinants-with-three-variables) might provide some useful examples if you're interested.

You can use any method you like to come up with $det\ A_i$, for small matrices standard rules or cofactor expansion might work out fine, for larger matrices you can use row operations to get to a triangular matrix or at least a matrix with a bunch of zero entries as described [here](https://math.dartmouth.edu/archive/m8s00/public_html/handouts/matrices3/node7.html).

I've been trying to find a proper proof of Cramers's rule explicitly using the adjunct, but I can't seem to find it. The best proof I've actually found is [outlined here](http://www.mathamazement.com/Lessons/Pre-Calculus/08_Matrices-and-Determinants/cramers-rule.html), while the most promising sounding proof, *Robinson, Stephen M. (1970). "A Short Proof of Cramer's Rule". Mathematics Magazine*, sadly doesn't seem to be available online (or anywhere else really).